returned status value 6 and status text "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."
Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "QUANTITY" returned status value 6 and status text "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
I am completely new to SSIS and trying to import a csv file with a column called "QUANTITY".  What datatype do i put in the data source advanced section so that there won't be an error?
I've tried two-byte signed integer, eight-byte signed integer... not sure what to do

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
